# Insert List valuesinto SQlite3 database with Python error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
ctime = []
name = []
minprice = []
maxprice = []
stock = []
historical_sold = []
sold = []
option_name = []
option_stock = []
option_price = []


#Connect to SQL database
conn = sqlite3.connect('etracker.db')

#Create cursor to work with database
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''Create TABLE if not exists server("prices")''')




with open('eurls.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        asins.append(row[0])
        asin = asin
    date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    url = f"https://e.{tld}/api/item/get"

    querystring = {"itemid":f"{itemid}","shopid":f"{shopid}"}

    payload = ""
    headers = {
        "cookie": "SPC_SI=9egeYgAAAABlNUJsazZUbPQ60gAAAAAAeVpFRmJWb00%3D; REC_T_ID=c56cc396-9f13-11ec-b054-2cea7fad64d2;",
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    # json object
    result_json = response.json()

    # starting point
    result = result_json['data']

    # These are the results from the API based on starting point ['data']

    name = result['name']
    minprice = result['price_min']/100000
    maxprice = result['price_max']/100000
    stock = result['normal_stock']
    historical_sold = result['historical_sold']
    sold = result['sold']

    # starting point
    option_items = result_json['data']['models']
    
    for option_item in option_items:
        
        # option name
        try:
            option_name.append(option_item['name'])
        except:
            option_name.append('')
                    
        # option stock
        try:
            option_stock.append(option_item['normal_stock'])
        except:
            option_stock.append('')
                    
        # option price
        try:
            option_price.append(option_item['price']/100000)
        except:
            option_price.append('')

        print(option_name, option_stock, option_price)



    print(date, name, minprice, maxprice, stock, historical_sold, sold, asin)



    c.execute('''INSERT INTO prices VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (date, name, minprice, maxprice, stock, historical_sold, sold, asin))
    print(f'Added data for {name}, {minprice}')

    #Insert links into table
    def data_entry():
        for item in option_name:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO server(prices) VALUES(?)", (option_name))
        #conn.commit()

    data_entry()  # ==> call the function

  
conn.commit()
```

I am getting an error and unable to add those to the SQL database as some products may have 3 options some may have 20 options

How do I handle that? I read that I need to loop through the list and insert it but when I tried it I get this error

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 11, and there are 8 supplied.

Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, this is for a Single Product where we are running once a day to get the data so all the data above should be in 1 row.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if the product has 5 options or 10 options or 15 options so for each option there will be a
option_name
option_price
option_stock

and if there are 15 options, they will all go into the same row but on multiple columns